# Can "stylizable" be used in this context?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, word-usage

We need a term to describe an element with an customizable look (for example, if it's a text, one can customize its font and foreground color). Can we use the term "**stylizable**" for that?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. *Stylizable* (see *[stylize](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stylize)* ODO) is a legitimate English word. The word already has an established meaning and usage.
2. See if your need fits the definition, else choose another term.
3. From what is mentioned, it seems you need a different term instead. Why not *[customizable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/customizable)* (ODO)?

HTH.

Comment: Google Search Engine doesn't show the word 'Stylizable' that you provided, not even in dictionaries like Cambridge and Oxford.

Comment: @IqbalAhmedSiyal Just lick on the link provided.